# Rails autoloading: constants are lost between tests or a circular dependency is introduced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hierarchy, autoload

I've run into an issue with how Rails autoloading works in development/test environments. What I'm trying to achieve is sort of pluggable implementations for a parent class, that can be modified on application start. In more detail, I have implemented a class `Measure` with the following idea:

```rb
# app/models/measure.rb
class Measure

  attr_reader :implementations

  def self.register(klass)
    @implementations << klass
  end

  def self.from(raw_value)
    # ... find a suitable implementation and instantiate it
  end

  # ...
end
```

And then I have implementations of the different `Measures` such as:

```rb
# app/models/measures/grams.rb
module Measures
  class Grams < Measure
    # ... code to tell Measures if this class can be 
    # instantiated from a given raw value
  end
end
```

These should then be set up with calls such as `Measure.register(Measures::Grams)`.

The issue is, if I do this in an initializer, the measure implementations are lost between test runs as the constant cache is apparently purged. That means, a call such as `Measure.from("2 grams")` that should be valid, no longer works as `Measure.implementations` does not contain `Measures::Grams`. If, on the other hand, I add a `require_dependency` in `app/models/measure.rb`, referencing some code that does the registrations, I have a circular dependency when referencing one of the implementations before Rails has loaded the `Measure` class. After quite a bit of fiddling around and reading up on how Rails does autoloading, I haven't been able to come up with a satisfying solution.

So my question is: how should this hierarchy be set up to play nice with how Rails autoloads code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I've found a way to work around this by moving the responsibility of keeping track of registered implementations from the `Measure` base class to the `Measures` module, and also doing the registrations in the same file as the module is defined. It seems to me like a more sound architectural choice, too. Only thing left to do is to differentiate the names with more than an 's'-affix.